# How can I avoid repetitive code using reference types?

Tags: c#, readability

I've made a method to split address line into separate distinct categories like Region, City, Street and House which are represented by a single class. It follows relatively simple structure.

```
Address useOther(string Casual, string Other)
    {
        Address
            address = new Address();

        List<string>
            split = new List<string>();
        char[]
            separator = { ',' };
        split.AddRange(
            Casual.Split(
                separator, 
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
        split.AddRange(
            Other.Split(
                separator, 
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

        // Initialize parameters
        split = RemoveBannedTokens(split);

        for (int i = 0; i < split.Count; i++)
        {
            (address.Region, split[i]) = findRegionByName(split[i]);

            if (address.Region != null)
            {
                split[i] = split[i].Replace(address.Region.Name, "");
                break;
            }
        }

        if (address.Region == null)
        {
            address.Region = new Region(region);
        }

        split = ClearSplit(split);

        // Finding region
        for (int i = 0; i < split.Count; i++)
        {
            (address.City, split[i]) = findSityByName(split[i]);

            if (address.City != null)
            {
                split[i] = split[i].Replace(address.City.Name, "");
                break;
            }

        }
        if (address.City == null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < split.Count; i++)
            {
                (address.City, split[i]) = findCityByName(split[i], false);

                if (address.City != null)
                {
                    split[i] = split[i].Replace(address.City.Name, "");
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
        if (address.City == null)
            return address;
        split = ClearSplit(split);

        // Finding city
        for (int i = 0; i < split.Count; i++)
        {
            (address.Street, split[i]) = findStreetByName(split[i], address.City);

            if (address.Street != null)
            {
                split[i] = split[i].Replace(address.Street.Name, "");
                break;
            }
        }
        if (address.Street == null && 
            (address.Region.Code.Replace("/", "") + 
             address.City.Code.Replace("/", "")).Length != 13)
            return address;
        split = ClearSplit(split);
        //Finding street

        int
            cityIndex = address.City.Index,
            streetIndex = address.Street.Index;

        for (int i = 0; i < split.Count; i++)
        {
            split[i] = split[i].Replace("б/н", "");
        }
        address.House = findNumbers(split.ToArray(), cityIndex, streetIndex);

        return address;
    }
```

If you can see repetition goes like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < split.Count; i++)
{
    (address.Something, split[i]) = findSomethingByName(split[i]);

    if (address.Something != null)
    {
        //do this thing
        break;
    }

}
if (address.Something == null)
    //try other thing
split = ClearSplit(split);
```

I want to avoid this repetition and have something of an array or foreach loop but couldn't find a clear way of making an array with reference values or a foreach reference loop that would work with null values properly. I have thought about making a function with specified inputs and outputs but decide it would only harm ability to read my code, which I'm trying to improve here.

Comment: `(address.Street, split[i]) = findStreetByName(...` does this compile?

Comment: Of coure it is, code is working as intended. I use tuples as an output for the leftover string after I used it in a function and use it later.

Comment: please tell me what's the C# grammer here and what C# version supports it?

Comment: I use .NET Framework 4.7.2, so it's C# 8 I assume

Comment: As for the grammar it is C# tuple, C# 7 or above support this

Comment: Where are the missing methods… `findRegionByName(split[i]);`, `findSityByName(split[i]);`, `findStreetByName(split[i], address.Sity);` and other missing items … ? …

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was irrelevant to the question itself, If needed I could provide you with them

Comment: how will `address` be used later? i doubt if you really need delcare the properties, i think `dictionary<propertyname, value>` should be ok, hense for loop can solve the repeative code. or reflection might help if you cannot change `address` declaration.

Comment: `address` used as a container for instances of my class. It would be really troublesome to make dictionary instead, since `Region` (name of my class) has a bunch of usefull fields I use all the time like `FullName, Name, Code, Index, Token` etc. As for reflection I didn't learn this cocept yet, so I can't say rn if it would be helpful

Comment: I will look further into reflection tho to see if it helps me

Comment: you can also use private dictionary internally, then the properties `get` will return value from dictionary. i think this is the best compromise.

Comment: Sorry, I can't make sense of what are you proposing and how will it help me, could you please elaborete on this?

Comment: I think I'd leave it alone and move on with my life. There are things you could do to compact it some, declaring a method that takes Action/Func of which methods to call/which properties to set but it will reduce the glanceability quite a bit. Perhaps everywhere you have a comment like //finding city, I would break it up into a method called FindingCity etc so it's not one massive method.. it would be helpful to see what raw data in you're working with to see if the entire operation could be restructured

Comment: No need, the code is pretty clear as it is, and adding a layer of abstraction is going make the code less readable. Besides it is not likely there are going to be hundreds of fragments of code needed, as you have covered the required functionality with just a few "repetitions". I would just leave it alone, **unless you have to** for some unspecified reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thinking and looking on how I could manage this, I have decided to follow JAlex advise. For now I don't think this change is necessary, so I leave it be for now. What I will do is I would try make this more readable by using additional spaces and comments. As of for now my method looks something like this (after a bit of tweaking here and there) and I'm more or less happy with how readable it is

```
Address useOther(string Casual, string Other)
{
    Address address = 
        new Address();
    //Initialize address

    List<string> split = 
        new List<string>();
    char[] separator = 
    { 
        ',' 
    };
    //Initialize split and separators

    split.AddRange(Casual.Split(separator));
    split.AddRange(Other .Split(separator));
    RemoveBannedTokens(ref split);
    //Fill split



    for (int i = 0; i < split.Count; i++)
    {
        (address.Region, split[i]) = 
            findRegionByName(split[i]);

        if (address.Region != null)
            break;
    }
    //Trying to find region

    if (address.Region == null)
        address.Region = new Region(region);
    //If Region is not found

    ClearSplit(ref split);
    //Get rid of empty strings



    for (int i = 0; i < split.Count; i++)
    {
        (address.City, split[i]) = 
            findSityByName(split[i]);

        if (address.City != null)
            break;
    }
    //Trying to find city

    if (address.City == null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < split.Count; i++)
        {
            (address.City, split[i]) = 
                findSityByName(split[i], false);

            if (address.City != null)
                break;
        }
    }
    //Trying to find city with additional params

    if (address.City == null)
        return address;
    //If City is not found

    ClearSplit(ref split);
    //Get rid of empty strings



    for (int i = 0; i < split.Count; i++)
    {
        (address.Street, split[i]) = 
            findStreetByName(split[i], address.City);

        if (address.Street != null)
            break;
    }
    //Trying to find street

    string code =
        address.Region.Code.Replace("/", "") +
        address.City.Code  .Replace("/", "");
    //Initialize code

    if (address.Street == null && code.Length != 13)
        return address;
    //If Street is not found and address is not complete

    ClearSplit(ref split);
    //Finding street

    address.House = findNumbers(split);
    //Trying to find house

    return address;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to demonstrate your problem and my proposal.

*Assumptions*

1. Your class has several similiar properties, all with value of `String`.
2. You have to keep the properties, because they may be required by other frameworks.
3. You have repeative code to work with the properties.

*OldAddress*

```cs
public class OldAddress
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
}
```

*Old Program*

```
public class Program
{

    static OldAddress oldAddress;

    public static string GetFromDataSource(string prop)
    {
        return null;//should return your real value
    }

    public static void AssignValueOldWay()
    {
        if (oldAddress.City != null)
        {
            oldAddress.City = GetFromDataSource("City");
        }
        if (oldAddress.Region != null)
        {
            oldAddress.Region = GetFromDataSource("Region");
        }
        // more...
    }
}
```

*NewAddress*

```cs
public class NewAddress
{
    public static string[] PropNames = { "City", "Region" };
    public NewAddress()
    {
        props = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (string prop in PropNames)
        {
            props.Add(prop, "");
        }
    }

    public string City
    {
        get
        {
            return GetProperty("City");
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty("City", value);
        }
    }
    public string Region
    {
        get
        {
            return GetProperty("Region");
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty("Region", value);
        }
    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> props;

    public void SetProperty(string prop, string value)
    {
        props[prop] = value;
    }

    public string GetProperty(string prop)
    {
        return props[prop];
    }

}
```

*New Program*

```cs
public class Program
{

    public static string GetFromDataSource(string prop)
    {
        return null;//should return your real value
    }

    static NewAddress newAddress;

    public static void AssignValueNewWay()
    {
        foreach (string prop in NewAddress.PropNames)
        {
            if (newAddress.GetProperty(prop) != null)
            {
                newAddress.SetProperty(prop, GetFromDataSource(prop));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note my code is just to demonstrate the idea, not optimized for runtime exceptions or bad styles such as public fields, or magic strings.

Answer (score 0):

I had some spare time, so I decided to refactor your code as a mental exercise for myself.

I still wanted to post my solution in case you are interested in seeing it. The most fundamental shift is that I oriented my thoughts from [imperative programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) to [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) which resulted in a more concise code, and for people used to this paradigm, a much more readable code.

```
Address userOther(string Casual, string Other)
{
    var tokens = RemoveBannedTokens(Casual.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                          .Concat(Other.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                                          .ToList());

    //Region
    var regionResult = tokens.Select(findRegionByName).FirstOrDefault(t => t.Item1 != null);
    regionResult = regionResult == default ? (region, string.Empty) : regionResult;
    tokens.Remove(regionResult.Item2);

    //City
    var cityResult = tokens.Select(findSityByName).FirstOrDefault(t => t.Item1 != null);
    cityResult = cityResult == default ? tokens.Select(t => findCityByName(t, false)).FirstOrDefault(t => t.Item1 != null) : cityResult;
    cityResult = cityResult == default ? (default(City), string.Empty) : cityResult;
    if (cityResult.Item1 == null)
    {
        return new Address(regionResult.Item1);
    }
    tokens.Remove(cityResult.Item2);

    //Street
    var streetResult = tokens.Select(t => findStreetByName(t, cityResult.Item1)).FirstOrDefault(t => t.Item1 != null);
    if (streetResult.Item1 == null &&
        (regionResult.Item1.Code.Replace("/", "") + cityResult.Item1.Code.Replace("/", "")).Length != 13)
    {
        return new Address(regionResult.Item1, cityResult.Item1);
    }
    tokens.Remove(streetResult.Item2);

    return new Address(regionResult.Item1,
                       cityResult.Item1,
                       streetResult.Item1,
                       findNumbers(tokens.Select(t => t.Replace("б/н", "")).ToArray(), cityResult.Item1.Index, streetResult.Item1.Index));
}
```

A few things to note:

- Since you didn't provided some methods used by this one, I was unable to test the real behavior of this approach
- I assumed that the returned second item of tuple from methods `findXXXByName` was the same as the value provided and didn't bother to update `tokens[i]` with it
- the variable `region` is provided nowhere in your example, but I still decided to keep it as is
- I created `Address` instances just when returning them, which forced me to declare multiple constructors (which you may not currently have)
- I assumed that `ClearSplit()` was just removing empty strings from the tokens

I hope you will find this bit of code valuable for your career path and personnal learning.